# Custom IIS ARR rewrite provide when hosting ARR in an Azure WebApp

Tags: azure, iis, proxy, azure-web-app-service

We are hosting IIS ARR in a webapp running as a basic reverse proxy. This is working well and is really easy to configure (unlike the alternative we considered, Azure Application Gateway).

Our proxy takes an incoming url and simply forwards it to a different server so nothing too complicated.

What we need to do now though is to add a url rewrite rule for a tenanted endpoint, so with a url like this:

```
https://proxy/[customerid]/stuff?id=1
```

for **customer A** rewrite to

```
https://tenantservera/[customerid]/stuff?id=1
```

and for **customer B** rewrite to

```
https://tenantservera/[customerid]/stuff?id=1
```

Customers could be added at any time, and there are a number of these proxy servers deployed worldwide running behind Azure Traffic Manager, so I would prefer to avoid updating the web.config each time we add a new customer if at all possible.

This appears to be possible (though a bit archaic) with a "real" server running IIS as you can write a custom module in .NET 2.0, deploy to server's GAC and then hook it into the pipeline in IIS. This would update the web.config something like this:

```
<providers>
  <provider name="DB" type="DbProvider, Microsoft.Web.Iis.Rewrite.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
    <settings>
      <add key="StoredProcedure" value="GetRewrittenUrl" />
    </settings>
  </provider>
</providers>
```

Does anyone know if this, or anything like it, is possible in a web application? We can't install into the GAC AFAIK.